# Windows Virtual Desktops - Doubts

Tags: windows, virtualization, azure, desktop

I am looking for some solutions to avoid buying laptops and one that I found is: Windows Virtual Desktop.
I used azure calculator for:

**Windows Virtual Desktop** 
Region East US 2 
Type Pooled 
100 named users 
1 peak concurrency 
0,1 off peak concurrency 
220 usage hours/month 
Session Multi-session 
Workload type Power 
Instance D4s v3 4 vCPU(s) 16 GB RAM 32 GB Temporary storage 
25 instances 
Managed OS - Premium SSD - P10 128 GiB - 25 Disks 

**Azure Firewall** 
Region East US 2 
Firewall Deployment 1x 220 hours 
Data processed 200 GB 

**VPN Gateway** 
Region East US 2 
Type VPN Gateways 
Gateway type Basic VPN 
220 Hours 
Outbound 50 GB 

**Storage Account** 
Capacity 1000 GB

**Bandwidth** 
Internet Egress - Brazil South - Public Internet 
50 GB Outbound Transfer 

It is my first time with Azure, so I do not know if I am provisioning something wrong. 
All I described above is enough to 100 users work in a Virtual Desktop? I mean:

- The performance will be ok? Security will be ok?
- I will be able to connect a vpn S2S with five local sites?
- I will be able to extend my ip address from intranet to the virtual desktops?
- I missed anything to make it to work?
- And why I need a Storage account if I already have the Managed disks?

Sorry for dumb questions. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How will users be connecting to the virtual desktops?

Answer (score 1):

The question is impossible to answer as it is. It needs a whole case study, proper design and capacity planning.

Starting with the Azure Calculator without exactly knowing what you need is exactly the wrong way to go; especially if, as you said, "this is your first time with Azure".

This is exactly the scenario where you need someone who knows what s/he is doing. Please call someone with actual expertise, either a consultant or a consulting company.

Trying to get something done by trial and error is the worst possible way to approach a project like this.